# Não somar campo se coluna igual Mysql

Tags: mysql

Opa,

Estou somando o total de uma coluna double, o que preciso é que, a consulta não some esta coluna caso a coluna Cod seja igual.
Explicando melhor, a coluna cod pode se repetir, caso ela se repita o valor da coluna desconto também se repetirá, ou seja, não somar o desconto caso tenha uma outra cod igual

```
Select sum(desconto) From ordem where cod != cod and data='2015-10-29'
```

Comment: Qual linguagem você está usando na aplicação? PHP?

Comment: Aqui na empresa ainda usando VB6

Comment: Não conheço VB, mas sei resolver seu problema usando logica com PHP. Ajudaria? Você conseguiria adaptar?

Comment: Por favor, pode mandar, caso seja alteração direta na sql será melhor

Answer (score 0):

Quando você coloca `cod != cod` você está comparando o código com ele mesmo.

Uma alternativa seria agrupar pelo código e pegar somente os grupos que tem uma ocorrencia:

```
select sum(t.total) 
from (select sum(desconto) total 
      from venda 
      group by cod 
      having count(*) = 1) as t
```

Comment: Opa, funcionou parcialmemnte, ele não somou os descontos com o Cod igual, ele deve caso não seja igual adicionar o campo a soma, caso seja igual, adicionar apenas um campo desconto a soma. desculpe-me se não expliquei bem

Comment: select cod , sum(desconto) total .........having count(cod) = 1)